# wp_get_attachment_image_src() works on index, but not on Archives

Tags: post-thumbnails, images

I'm customizing a client theme and he asked me to do this: when a user clicked on thumbnail of a post on index and archives, the large size of post thumbnail shows up in a lightbox.
So I've got the large size of post thumbnail using:

```
<?php $page_id = get_queried_object_id(); ?>
<?php $thumbs_array = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($page_id), 'large' ); ?>
<?php $large_thumb = $thumbs_array[0]; ?>
```

and put the `$large_thumb` value on the appropriate tag as `data-*`, like:

```
<div class="img lightbox-trigger" data-large-thumb="<?php echo $large_thumb ?>">                
    <?php the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail'); ?>
</div><!-- .img .lightbox-trigger -->
```

And I show that in a lightbox using snippet of jQuery.

Now on index, all things work just fine and perfect. But when I check Archive pages, it doesn't work like it should. I check the generated source and saw the `data-large-thumb` on archives is Empty!, where on index `data-large-thumb` has the address of Thumbnail's large size in it.

The weird thing is, needed markup called from the same file using `get_template_part`. I mean when I check `index.php` and `archive.php` both has

```
<?php get_template_part( 'col-h' );?>
```

which load codes from same file, but this same file returns value on `index` and Nothing on `archive`, when I `var_dump($large_thumb)` it's `NULL`. That's weird I think!

Generated results on `index.php`:

```
<div class="img lightbox-trigger" data-large-thumb="http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/Desert-1024x768.jpg">                 
    <img src="http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/Desert-150x150.jpg" class="attachment-thumbnail size-thumbnail wp-post-image" width="150" height="150">
</div>
```

and on `archive.php`:

```
<div class="img lightbox-trigger" data-large-thumb="">              
    <img src="http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/Desert-150x150.jpg" class="attachment-thumbnail size-thumbnail wp-post-image" width="150" height="150">
</div>
```

**Update**
I var_dumped those 3 related variables to know what they returns. On index:

```
$page_id returns 0
$thumbs_array return correct array containing url, width, height, etc
$large_thumb returns url of large thumbnail
```

and Everything works just fine on `index`. but on `archive` pages:

```
$page id returns proper value; 2, 3, 8, 10 or whatever the ID is
$thumbs_array returns `bool(false)`
$large_thumb returns`NULL`
```

So it seems the problem is related to `wp_get_attachment_image_src` which doesn't work on Archive unfortunately.
Is there any other WP function which I should use ? why it returns False ?

What I'm missing here ?

And Please let me know if any additional information needed to solve this.

Thanks.

Comment: Ok...I suspected to this custom theme that I'm working on, so I test these codes mentioned on different site, with totally different theme, and I faced the exact issue. `$large_thumb` has the address of large thumbnail image on `index` and Nothing on `archives`. Is that something wrong with using `get_queried_object_id` on archive or what ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`get_queried_object_id` will return the ID for the object that is queried (obviously). On archive pages, that would be the ID of the archive – unless your archive has a thumbnail, you're not going to get an image.

Depending on where you're setting the `$large_thumb` variable, you should be able to omit the ID altogether (as long as it's used within the loop) using [the `get_the_post_thumbnail_url()`-function](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_post_thumbnail_url/).

If you place your code right above the code to display the image, it should work:

```
<?php
$large_thumb = get_the_post_thumbnail_url(null, 'large');
// Notice the null-value, instead of providing a post ID or object, will default to the current global $post.
?>
<div class="img lightbox-trigger" data-large-thumb="<?php echo $large_thumb ?>">                
    <?php the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail'); ?>
</div><!-- .img .lightbox-trigger -->
```

Comment: What a mistake... this wasted hours of my time!
your solution works great, I appreciate your help Emil.

Comment: You're welcome! You can find more info about the loop and how it works here: https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/the-loop/

Comment: That's a good resource Emil. Again, thank you so much.